# Why am I receiving a "cannot determine custom face code" error when importing my character?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I am trying to import my face from Mass Effect 2 (which was originally from Mass Effect 1) and I get the following error:

> Mass Effect 3 cannot successfully determine the face code used by this imported save game. Please update your character's appearance.

Is there any reason or fix for this? I no longer have Mass Effect 1 or 2.

Comment: This is on 360, but also seems to be an issue on other platforms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems it's a problem with ME3's character import system.

[SOURCE](http://kotaku.com/5890793/oh-dear-mass-effect-3s-character-import-isnt-working-properly)

EDIT: EA knows about the issue. For now, you'll have to recreate the face yourself.

[EA'S ME3 Import Save File page](http://help.ea.com/article/will-i-be-able-to-import-a-save-file-from-steam-into-mass-effect-3)

Comment: This really sucks, the new faces are terrible.

Comment: I've only just started Mass Effect 1 on PC.. So I have lots of time for the bugs to get ironed out. My sympathies are with you, though.

Comment: Bioware has released a statement that [they have fixed the bug](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/323/index/9661093) so there *will* be an upcoming patch to fix it. However, the patch still has to pass certification, so there's no ETA.